# Passport Not Stamped on Entering Sweden

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, passport-stamps, sweden

I have a flight from India - Munich where they just scanned my passport and saw my Work permit of Sweden but didn't stamped on my passport.

On reaching Sweden there was no immigration check and directly came outside with no stamp on my passport.

What to do. Is this right or I need to get it stamped again ?

Comment: Is it the fist time you're travelling on this work permit? In principle, my reading of the rules is that you should have received a stamp in Munich but I hear that practice is a little inconsistent and in many cases it doesn't matter much.

Comment: @Inderpreet , same situation for me yesterday .is it everyting fine ? or should i check with swedish immigration authorities ?

Answer (score 9):

Not clearing immigration in Sweden was correct, because the Schengen Area (of which Germany and Sweden are part) functions as a single country, which you entered at Munich.

In addition, Germany is one of the Schengen countries that do **not** stamp passports of holders of residence permits. Although it lacks support in the Schengen Borders code, that is actual practice.

Thus, you will have no problems.

Comment: On what authority does Germany refrain from stamping holders of residence permits?  The Schengen Borders Code seems to require it.

Comment: @phoog Don't know, but I've made enough observations to safely say that that's actual practice (as well in at least Slovenia and Switzerland)

Comment: When Spain accused me of an overstay (on a separate visit a year later), I produced the bus ticket for my departure, and bank records showing I had used an ATM in London the next day.

Answer (score 4):

Your passport should have been stamped **in Munich** when you arrived in the Schengen zone from India.

If you did not get an entry stamp *there*, something is wrong.  You'll probably need to contact the Swedish immigration authorities (try the nearest police station first) to figure out what you should do to regularize your documentation. Hopefully you still have boarding passes or other documentation for when you arrived in the Schengen area.

Comment: OP has a residence Permit, and so Needs no stamp

Comment: @Crazydre: There's nothing in the Borders Code about not stamping residence permit holders. There's an exception for family members with Article 10 cards, but all other third nationals are supposed to get stamps on entry and exit.

Comment: Actual practice at the border is different though: I know Sweden, France and Hungary stamp holders of residence permits, while Germany, Switzerland and Slovenia do not. I have enough observations by far to safely say that that's what applies in practice